# Updaing Kernel while having Xorg Driver installed

Tags: 12.04, kernel, xorg

On my system I've installed Ubuntu **12.04** with kernel **3.7.8-030708-generic** and **Xorg** graphics driver. Now I want to upgrade my kernel to **3.8.2**. So will it effect my **Xorg driver**. If does, then what steps should I take to keep running my **Xorg driver** as well as **update my kernel**?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Kernel and Xorg are to, in some sense, independent things. To update your kernel go to the 
http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/
and download 4 kernels according to your system

32bit - linux-image-xxx-i386, linux-image-extra-xxx-i386, linux-headers-xxx-i386 and linux-headers-all.deb

64bit - linux-image-xxx-amd64, linux-image-extra-xxx-amd64, linux-headers-xxx-amd64 and linux-headers-all.deb

then open the terminal and locate the folder you downloaded all the files, let's say Download folder

```
cd Downloads
```

Then make sure you do not have any other files in the download directory (I mean other .deb files) to make sure it won't mess up the installation and install the kernel

```
sudo dpkg -i linux*.deb
```

That's it!

Comment: thanks. and I know how to update kernel, I was just asking if there would be any conflict while updating kernel. thanks again